# Does time pass on a Terraria server when no one is present?

Tags: terraria

On a Terraria dedicated server, does time pass if no one is playing?

I ask because I've started farming, and it would mean I can simply leave a dedicated server running without being connected, and still have grass spread.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**No**, time does not pass and world updates do not occur when no players are connected. You can easily verify that by issuing the `time` command a couple times with no players present — you'll see that the in-game time doesn't change.

You used to be able to keep a world going by just loading it with the server software, but this was changed in [patch 1.0.5](https://store.steampowered.com/news/5716/):

> **Server**
>
> - Servers now hibernate when no players are connected.

Comment: Guess I could just leave a disposable character in there instead. Thank you.