# Do plants grow while I'm in another world?

Tags: terraria

I'm playing Terraria 1.2.4.1 for PC and I've got to the point where I just have to scratch the itch of wanting a cool base, and I also want to set up some farms beneath the ground for things like Daybloom and Glowing Mushrooms.

When I've planted the farms, will they continue to grow while I'm playing in another world, or do I have to be putting time into the base-world for things in there to grow?

Comment: Also some things won't grow under the ground. Eg day bloom needs sunlight to blossom

Comment: @Daniel I've knocked out the dirt background wall and installed a glass wall behind it. Will that count as daylight?

Comment: It will if you can see sky behind it. If you see rocks then it is too far underground.

Comment: @Daniel yeah - I can't screeny as it's on my laptop at home, but it's in the dirt layer, about 20 blocks below surface, but with the dirt knocked out so the overworld Forest background comes through, then a glass wall to stop enemies, allow light in and look nice

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Time in the "base world" actually has to pass for things to grow, corruption/hallow to spread, etc. For anything to happen basically.

So **no**, plants won't grow if you're off looting someworld else.

An addition/exception by Bob from the comments below: The player doesn't have to be physically in the world; the world just has to be running. One can leave the world running using the dedicated server launcher.

Comment: There is an exception: AFAIK the *player* doesn't have to be physically in the world; the world just has to be running. You can leave the world running using the dedicated server launcher.

Comment: @Bob interesting. Can that run my base world while I'm playing my character in another world?

Comment: @Joe It should, yes. (Note: I haven't actually confirmed this, and it's been a while since I last played Terraria. It's *possible* that the dedicated server pauses processing when there's no players connected. I do not believe this to be the case, and it's simple enough to test. I do remember a whole lot of crimson after leaving the server running overnight...)

Comment: @Bob and Joe, Bob's initial thought is correct, as long as the map is running in a server instance then time is being simulated. (Source: I was doing this last night :P )

Comment: @Bob You should add that (read: edit in) to the above answer.

Comment: @ryan How did you test that? I tested on my own MP server (running on tshock) using the `time` command and got the opposite result-- The time when I left and the time when I returned were the same, even though over 5 minutes had passed in real time. [This post](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/31932/does-time-pass-when-no-one-is-present) also seems to support my conclusion.

Comment: @JohnCleaver I'm using the tAPI server so our results may be different. I guess for a real answer we would have to use the default Terraria server, since other implementations may very. As far as testing it, My server always starts at dawn, so if I join right as I bring the server up I always start playing at dawn. However, last night, I stayed in a single player world for a bit before getting on my server and when I did it was the middle of the night.

Comment: @Bob and Joe - I used to run 4 worlds simultaneously for AFK farming, waiting for blood moons (before they fixed the corrupted goldfish).  The basic server wouldn't pause when you minimize it, so you did not want to be in bad spots.  My "greenhouses" would always fill up.  I did think that you had to have a character in the world though.

Answer (score 3):

The world is not actually being simulated while you are not in it, so no time is passing and nothing else will actually happen. Even if you run a dedicated multiplayer server, the simulation stops if there are no players in the world. You can imagine it would be problematic if, for example, the corruption continued to spread while you were not playing the game. The same principle applies to plants. They will not grow when the world is not loaded with a player in it.